# Can't pass int to UIView with drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, setneedsdisplay

How do I pass an int to a UIView that is using drawRect to make me a circle arc?

I'm trying to draw a circle arc, and every second, call setNeedsDisplay on the UIView with an int advanced by one (secs). This doesn't seem to be calling and remains (null) when I call `NSLog(@"draw, %d",self.secs);`

basically my code log just reads "draw 1" followed by "draw 0" every second.

draw.h

```
@property (nonatomic) int secs;
```

draw.m

```
@synthesize secs;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"draw, %d",self.secs);
    //stuff with using this value   
}
@end
```

main VC.m - NSTimer calls this, but tick.secs seems to be 0 every time

```
draw *tick = [[draw alloc] init];
tick.secs = tick.secs+1;
NSLog(@"draw, %d",tick.secs);
[self.drawView setNeedsDisplay];
```

EDIT 1:

Stonz2 is quite correct, I should use an instance `draw` - this has solved half of my problem. Now in my main VC.m, `tick.secs` is increasing every second, but in draw.m, drawRect still thinks `secs` is 0 every second

EDIT 2:
Sha fixed it with his observation of my IBOutlet using UIView, not draw

Comment: How is `draw` class relates to `self.drawView` property?

Comment: drawView is the name of the IBOutlet hooked up to the UIView with class draw

Comment: Why then you're allocating another `draw` object each time, instead of using `self.drawView.secs` property?

Comment: I've stopped the allocating of draw each time (as below answer), and that's helped part of the problem. if I do self.drawView.secs, I get an error: Property 'secs' not found on object of type 'UIView *'

Comment: Then you don't have proper outlet configured. You need to change class on the UIView in storyboard to be `draw`.

Comment: Yeah, I have that as the UIView class in storyboard, which is why I'm super confused

Comment: It should be `draw` not `UIView` in storyboard

Comment: Please post code where IBOutlet is defined and screenshot from your storyboard.

Comment: `@interface...{
UIView *drawView;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView *drawView;`

Comment: Exactly... It's UIView, and should be `draw`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new `draw` object every time you run through your timed method. You need to keep the same reference to your `draw` object if you want to maintain its properties.

Consider creating an instance `draw` object in your main VC.m file instead of creating a new one every time you run your timed method.

Example:

```
@implementation mainVC
{
    draw *tick;
}

...

- (void)startTimer
{
    tick = [[draw alloc] init];
    tick.secs = 0;
    // start your timer here
}

- (void)timerIncrement
{
    // do NOT alloc/init your draw object again here.
    tick.secs += 1;
    [self.drawView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, I should have known that - getting there. Now tick.secs is increasing nicely in my VC.m, but in drawRect, it is still at 0 every second - any thoughts?

Comment: FYI - it would be better to have the `setSecs:` method of the `draw` class call `setNeedsDisplay` instead of requiring every client of the `draw` class need to do it.